# Devices keep getting IP from previous VLAN

Tags: dhcp, vlan, dhcp-server, ipv4

Some devices (printers and laptops) that are moved to another building with a different VLAN will not release the IP address assigned. I noticed this first when a laptop reported no network connectivity, but upon closer inspection noticed that it did get IP, network mask, DHCP, and DNS info from the DHCP server, but from another VLAN. It is just a few devices that have had this issue. For laptops, I have to take it back to the building that has that IP assigned and do an ipconfig /release, take it to the other building and then it gets the correct IP address.

I can't do the same for 2 printers. We tried setting a static IP address on the printer on both the DHCP server and on the printer itself, but it won't communicate at all and the DHCP server assigns the IP for the previous VLAN.

We only have one 2019 DHCP server and the IP helper is set correctly on the switches.

Update: I tried to spoof the MAC address of one of the printers on a laptop and connected it to the original switch VLAN. It got the same IP the printer has. I did an ipconfig /release, noticed that the DHCP deleted the IP lease, and went to the other building and reconnected the printer. Sadly, it got the same IP for the other building.

Comment: It's not a problem of the devices. The DHCP server cannot differentiate between the VLAN and tries to assign the same IP to the same network device. You need to adjust the settings for your DHCP server.

Comment: What specific settings do you suggest we look into? I noticed that they created superscopes for each of our campuses and within the supercopes there are the scopes for each building VLAN. The IP ranges look correct.

Comment: According to the below article, this is a known limitation of Microsoft DHCP Server SuperScopes. https://blog.mamc-llc.com/2019/05/06/why-you-should-never-use-microsoft-dhcp-superscopes/ "MS’s Superscope only works when you have multiple subnets sharing the same underlying VLAN, in which case, it works fine, and users would be OK maintaining their previous IP address, because the default gateway would continue to route traffic properly. However, because of the way that subnets and vlans work, every network administrator is going to assign only one subnet to vlan, instead of multiple."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when they created superscopes it really messed up the DHCP releases and assignments.
[This](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2173366-are-superscopes-breaking-my-dhcp) other forum post was helpful.

After they removed the superscopes, everything went back to normal.

Comment: According to the below article, this is a known limitation of Microsoft DHCP Server SuperScopes. https://blog.mamc-llc.com/2019/05/06/why-you-should-never-use-microsoft-dhcp-superscopes/ "MS’s Superscope only works when you have multiple subnets sharing the same underlying VLAN, in which case, it works fine, and users would be OK maintaining their previous IP address, because the default gateway would continue to route traffic properly. However, because of the way that subnets and vlans work, every network administrator is going to assign only one subnet to vlan, instead of multiple."

Answer (score 1):

Your question is ambigious. "Some devices [...] are moved to another [...] VLAN. They did get IP [...] from another VLAN [...]". Isn't that what you want?

If you cannot communicate with even a static IP from that subnet/VLAN combination, then your network is not setup correctly. The ports on which your printer is plugged in is probably assigned the old VLAN still on the switch port where it connects.

There is no other way, as DHCP does not care that there is another lease for the same MAC address. The same device/MAC address can have multiple leases on DHCP server. As long as there are multiple scopes defined on the DHCP server, one for each subnet/VLAN. Make sure that every VLAN uniquely has its own subnet range.

Comment: When moved to another VLAN the device should get the IP from that VLAN. It is not. The devices still have the IP from the previous VLAN when connected on the new VLAN. The switch port has the correct VLAN. In fact the switch does not have the other building's VLAN on any port nor the trunk.

We removed the DHCP entry and when connecting the printer (Our current example that we are dealing with) it creates a lease IP from the old building VLAN.

Comment: The network guys did created superscopes for each campus. Within the superscopes there are scopes for each VLAN building of that campus. I checked the IP ranges for each scope and they are within thier respective ranges for the VLAN assigned.

Comment: I recommend checking all switches between the printer and the DHCP server. There might be a VLAN missing or a port misconfigured somewhere. Hard to tell without seeing the config

Comment: The switch where the printer is right now does not have the other building VLAN set at all. The core switch vlan info looks about right.

Comment: Okay but there can still be a wrong native VLAN configured on some other switch, or a port which should be a trunk is configured as access port